# CS-Script doesn't show up in Add Component search?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm using **Unity 2020.1.1f1**, when I try to add a *Component* to a *GameObject*, the component that I search for does not show up for me to add it? The component I have is located in a sub folder of Assets. Should I have imported it elsewhere? I have also restarted Unity to see if it would refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: It should derives from MonoBehaviour

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a thread on this already, I'll close this with the link: [Can't add script component because the script class cannot be found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51713497/cant-add-script-component-because-the-script-class-cannot-be-found)